# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt despite matplotlib installed and working

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, anaconda

I have read several of the issues related to the same problems but didn't find a solution.
I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed matplotlib in a conda environment called math.

```
conda install matplotlib
```

(conda 4.10.3)

No error, it went well it seems.
But then, when I launch a jupyter notebook and tries

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'
```

However, running

```
import matplotlib as plt
```

works without problem.

I launch the notebook from the conda math environment.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Command Prompt as admin.
2. Run `pip install matplotlib`
3. The problem may be resolved. Moreover check if you are running the latest version of Python.
4. If pip is not found. Reinstall Python. While reinstalling, remember to select "Add Python to path".

Hope it  helps..

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the problem by reinstalling Jupyter noteboook.